# Need to show Show More / Show Less option in JQGrid in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have requirement where I need to how Show More / Show Less option in a column appended to the values I am getting from DB eg: ABC, ABD, ABE,...Show More and vice versa when the full values are displayed if the length exceeds certain limit. Not sure how to achieve this scenario through jQuery. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Sample Table Structure is shown below.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
 1      Test  ABC, ABD,...Show More

Col1    Col2    Col3
 1      Test  ABC, ABD, ABE, ABF, ABG...Show Less
```

"Show More" and "Show Less" needs to be a hyperlink to activate a function to hide and how respectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

example:

i assume u are including ui.jqgrid.min.css and jquery.jqgrid.min.js.

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: 'your_data_url',
        datatype: 'json',
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Col1', index: 'Col1', width: 50 },
            { name: 'Col2', index: 'Col2', width: 100 },
            {
                name: 'Col3', index: 'Col3', width: 200,
                formatter: showMoreFormatter
            }
        ],
        // Other jqGrid options...
    });

    function showMoreFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        var maxLength = 10; // Maximum number of values to display
        var showMoreText = 'Show More';
        var showLessText = 'Show Less';

        var values = cellValue.split(','); // Assuming the values are comma-separated
        if (values.length > maxLength) {
            var displayedValues = values.slice(0, maxLength).join(', ');
            var hiddenValues = values.slice(maxLength).join(', ');

            return displayedValues + ', ' +
                '<a href="#" class="show-more-link" data-hidden-values="' + hiddenValues + '">' +
                showMoreText +
                '</a>';
        } else {
            return cellValue;
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.show-more-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this);
    var hiddenValues = link.data('hidden-values');
    var showMoreText = 'Show More';
    var showLessText = 'Show Less';

    if (link.text() === showMoreText) {
        link.text(showLessText);
        link.closest('tr').find('td[aria-describedby="grid_Col3"]').append(hiddenValues);
    } else {
        link.text(showMoreText);
        link.closest('tr').find('td[aria-describedby="grid_Col3"]').text(link.data('displayed-values'));
    }
});
```

Adjust the selector and attribute values in the JavaScript code according to the HTML structure produced by jqGrid. For the jqGrid setup, update 'your_data_url' with the authentic URL that retrieves the required data from the server. Note that both changes may be necessary.

For your unique data format and needs, it is possible to alter the code. In this case, assume the comma-separated string is returned for the 'Col3' column by the server.

Clicking on the "Show More" link within the 'Col3' column will grant access to a select number of values, while the link itself will undergo transformation into "Show Less" to once again secure the hidden data.

Hope this helps ! :)